# Update the metadata of current user in WordPress with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a button on my website posts to a PHP page. I can't seem to make my PHP code update the user meta data for the currently logged in user. The page is intended to allow users to change a specific meta key upon pressing the button. 
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
  if(isset ($_POST ['go']){
  $user_ID = $current_user->ID;
  $CustomMeta = "4";
  update_user_meta($user_ID, 'CustomMeta', $CustomMeta);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Current logged in user id -

`<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?>`

Comment: I have replaced the $user_ID line above with the code you supplied and it didn't work. Should I still be using the " -> "? Am I even going about this right at all? Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: Try this -
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_ID = $current_user->ID;

Answer (score 0):

Did you include wp-load.php in your page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't believe I have included or referenced this file. How should I go about doing this? Excuse my lack of knowledge, I'm a beginner and I don't have a flesh-and-blood instructor handy to turn to. :P